# Ruby Gosu using multiple folders

Tags: ruby, libgosu

i am working on a Ruby Gosu project and i was wondering if there was a way to access different code from multiple folders and connect them too a main base code,i believe this would make the overall project much less messy and i would not have to have one unorganized 500 line project. basically i want a command of sorts that will access and run code from other folders.

Comment: I don't know Gosu - is there some reason that Ruby's `require` or `require_relative` are not suitable?

Comment: Thank you, i will attempt too add this too my current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the files to one specific folder. You can do this manually or you can do it through the terminal or cmd, for example:

`$mkdir project`;`$mv myfile.rb ~/mydir/project` <= Linux commands, OSX are the same

`$mkdir project`;`$move myfile.rb /home/project` <= Windows commands

From there do `require_relative 'myfile.rb'` this will require the file for the program to run, example:

```
require_relative 'myfile.rb'

def some_name
  puts "something
end
```

If you don't want to do all that moving you can do `require` and give it the argument with the full path to the file, example:

```
require '/home/homedir/myfile.rb' #<= you can also use require_relative

def some_name
  puts "something"
end
```

Depending on how you want the file to be used and how often you can use `load 'filename'` the more Ruby way is to use `require 'filename'`or `require_relative 'filename'`, however.

`load` uses the file every time the method is executed, while `require` only loads the file once.

I'd highly suggest you read up on how to work with files and how to require files within a program: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/including_other_files_in_ruby.html